# Фильтр в DataGridView (Windows Forms)

Tags: .net, winforms, datagridview

Привет. Помогите реализовать строгий/не строгий поиск в `DataGridView`, как на скриншоте:[image: Фильтр в datagrid]

Код заполнения автоматически:

```
var dataSet = new DataSet();
dataSet.ReadXml("file.xml");
dataGridView1.DataSource = dataSet.Tables["offer"];
```

Пока реализовано так. До ручного заполнения ещё не дошёл.

Comment: покажите код, который заполняет DataGrid данными

Comment: дополнил вопрос кодом заполняющим datagrid

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для `DataTable` Grid View отображает `DefaultView` - у которого есть свойство для фильтрации, с поддержкой базового SQL-синтакса:

```
private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    (dataGridView1.DataSource as DataTable).DefaultView.RowFilter =
        String.Format("Country like '{0}%'", textBox1.Text);
}
```

Comment: Ну вы гении! Все работает. А сначала я поржал над ошибкой "не нашлось столбца "Country" ))

Comment: А еще чтобы не перезагружать xml как-то можно сделать reset поисковой фразы например на другой кнопке?

Comment: @Андрей можно - напишите в обработчике клика на этой кнопке `textBox1.Text = ""`

Comment: это немножко не то, оно просто очищает textbox, а не возвращает все строки xml )) Ну да ладно с этим. Я заметил что реализованный поиск ищет последовательно вводимые слова: пример "мама мыла раму", но не найдет "мыла раму мама". Как реализовать поиск без учета порядка слов? а? )) а там уже попробую сам сделать переключатель этих двух поисков

Comment: @Андрей, вам неплохо бы взять учебник по SQL и прочитать про SELECT. а так ответ на как искать без учета порядка слов лежит на поверхности `String.Format("Country like '%{0}%'", textBox1.Text);`

Comment: @Dmitry, да это работает при поиске 1 слова, а мне бы при поиске нескольких слов не учитывать порядок слов. Пример: 1) мама мыла раму 2) раму мыла мама 3) мыла раму мама 4) мыла мама раму 5) мама раму мыла 6) раму мама мыла. Вот чтобы при запросе мама рама - нашлись все эти варианты от 1) до 6). Можете помочь?

Comment: @Андрей разбивайте на отдельные слова и по ним уже делайте поиск, а лучше все-таки прочтите пару книжек одну про SELECT а другую по работе со строками на C#