# C# Фильтрация строк DataSet.Table в DataGridView

Tags: c#, datagridview, фильтр

Вечер добрый

```
public mainWindow() {
    InitializeComponent();

    for (int i = 1; i <= 15; i++) {
        callsTable.Rows.Add(new object[] { i, "" + (i * 111), null, null, null });
        cInfoTable.Rows.Add(new object[] { i, null });
    }
}

private void addButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    secondWindow sw = new secondWindow(callsTable, cInfoTable, -1);
    sw.Show();
}

private void openCall(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e) {
    secondWindow sw = new secondWindow(callsTable, cInfoTable, prosmotrTable.SelectedRows[0].Index);
    sw.Show();
}

private void search(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    //String search = " Описание LIKE '%" + srchTextBox.Text + "%'";
    //search += "OR  Местонахождение LIKE '%" + srchTextBox.Text + "%'";
    //search += "OR  Инициатор LIKE '%" + srchTextBox.Text + "%'";
    //search += "OR  Исполнитель LIKE '%" + srchTextBox.Text + "%'";

    (prosmotrTable.DataSource as DataTable).DefaultView.RowFilter = String.Format("Описание like '%{0}%'", srchTextBox.Text);
}
```

Метод search(текстБокса с реакцией на изменение теста) выкидывает исключение:

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException'
>   occurred in myTestsApp.exe Additional information: Ссылка на объект не
>   указывает на экземпляр объекта.

Не могу понять почему

Таблица, в которой происходит поиск - один из двух объектов DataSet'a

upd:

> DataSet ds = (DataSet)prosmotrTable.DataSource;
>
> DataTable dt = ds.Tables[0];
>
> dt.DefaultView.RowFilter = string.Format("Описание like '%{0}%'",
>   srchTextBox.Text);

Такой код не выкидывает ошибки, но и не фильтрует.

Comment: Скорее всего выражение `(prosmotrTable.DataSource as DataTable)`  оказывается равно `null`. Но это то, что в первую очередь бросается в глаза. А вообще, воспользуйтесь отладчиком и посмотрите какая из переменных у Вас оказалась `null`, когда Вы этого не ждали

Comment: В этом-то и вопрос. Почему она null.
[в этой теме] (http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/461044/%D0%A4%D0%B8%D0%BB%D1%8C%D1%82%D1%80-%D0%B2-datagrid-%D0%BD%D0%B0-c-xml) показан пример

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Самый главный вопрос - что Вы присваиваете `prosmotrTable.DataSource`? Лучше даже показать этот участок кода. Судя по функции `search`, Вы ожидаете там `DataTable` (`prosmotrTable.DataSource as DataTable)`. Однако, при обновлении вопроса приводится код, в котором источник данных Вы кастите к `DataSet` (`DataSet ds = (DataSet)prosmotrTable.DataSource;`). И, судя по тому, что при приведении к `DataTable` Вы получаете `null` и последующий `NullReferenceException`, а пример из `upd` не падает, там, все-таки `DataSet`. Проверьте, что Вы устанавливаете в качестве источника данных.

По приведенной [ссылке](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/461044/%D0%A4%D0%B8%D0%BB%D1%8C%D1%82%D1%80-%D0%B2-datagrid-%D0%BD%D0%B0-c-xml) дан правильный ответ, **НО** только при одном условии - в качестве источника данных должен быть установлен объект типа `DataTable`

Comment: Именно датасэт там и есть.
Находил на EU stackoverflow подобный вопрос, где приводились примеры с присваиванием туда и таблицы и сэта. С таблицей всё работало, а с сэтом нет. Ему дали точно такой же код (как по ссылке в этой теме) и он засчитан как ответ.


Несколько часов пытался опять откопать ту тему, но безуспешно.


Вопрос всё ещё открыт. Как отфильтровать Датагридвью, в котором DataSource - DataSet, DataMember - DataTable

Comment: @DenisJNewb, с привязкой через `DataSet` и `DataMember`, по крайней мере у меня, не получилось заставить работать. Скорее всего это связанно с особенностями использования `DataSet` в качестве источника данных

Comment: [Вот та ссылка](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5843537/filtering-datagridview-without-changing-datasource)
Нашел, тут аналогичная проблема, как мне кажется. Подскажет кто-нибудь как ему помогли? Некоторые проблемы с языком испытываю, поэтому до конца понять не могу.